# difference of join and jonedload in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relationship

I have the following classes:

```
Class User(Base):
    #user properties

Class Item(Base):
    #item properties

Class User_Item(Base):
    __tablename__='users_items'
    id=Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id=Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    item_id=Column(Integer, ForeignKey('items.id'))
    info=Column(String(20))
    user=relationship(User,backref='items',primaryjoin=(User.id==user_id))
    item=relationship(Item, backref='users',primaryjoin=(Item.id==item_id))
```

now what is the difference between the following two queries:

```
result1= session.query(Item).options(joinedload(Item.users)).filter(Item.users.any(user=user1)
```

or

```
result2=session.query(Item).join(Item.users).filter(Item.users.any(user=user1))
```

for some reason the second one looks weird! Let's say user1 has two items, running `result1.count()` returns 2 as expected, but `result2.count()` returns 3! While, `len(result2.all())` is 2! can somebody tell me, what is going on?! :D

Comment: What do you want to achieve with your query?

Comment: For example here I want to find all the Items that they are mapped to user1 (without using user1.items!!!) or a more realistic example is to find all the items with 'info="something"'. I think this is what I can achieve with the first query, but my question is how the first and the second query are diffrent?!

Comment: [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14340250/851737) on your other question might solve this problem, too...

Answer (score 0):

The first approach with `joinedload` is clearly not want you want, because it defines only how `item.users` is loaded after executing the query (see [Relationship Loading Techniques](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/loading.html)).

And with join, you should use `contains` instead of `any`:

```
result3 = session.query(Item).join(Item.users).filter(Item.users.contains(user1))
```

My guess is that your version with `any` produces multiple rows per join result. You can verify this by inspecting the produced SQL (set `echo=True` on engine configuration).

**Edit**

You might defined the many to many relationship wrong, this could be the real problem. In your version `User.items` and `Item.users` is both pointing to `User_Item` instead to User or Item and I think you are not aware of that.

You should have a look at the [Association Object Pattern](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/relationships.html#association-object) and how you can [simplify it](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#simplifying-association-objects).

Comment: First, thanks for the answers, but I still have two questions: 
1-in the first approach, I tried to load the Item.users and then query on top of that, since I can not query on attributes of users before loading it. It runs fine, is there any specific reason why it is not what I want?
2-Running your suggested query, gives me a StatementError!

Comment: Your first approach is just a more complicated way than accessing `user1.items` directly (without adding any real benefit). What is the error in the second case exactly? I still think you want a dynamic relationship so you can use `User.items` for a query (e.g. `user1.items.filter(Item.attribute==x).all()`).

Comment: I agree, dynamic relationship solves both of my problems in fact :) thanks :D